# jqgrid is not getting displayed in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, jqgrid

my jqgrid is not getting displayed,can anybody find error in my code.I have wore code in only aspx page.My code is

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >

<head runat="server">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="themes/redmond/jquery-ui-1.8.1.custom.css" />

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="themes/ui.jqgrid.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="themes/ui.multiselect.css" />
<script src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.1.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.layout.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/ui.multiselect.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.tablednd.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.contextmenu.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


<style type="text/css">    
    body, html { font-size: 80%; }     
       </style>


       <script type ="text/javascript" >
           var mydata = [
    { id: "1", invdate: "2010-05-24", name: "test", note: "note", tax: "10.00", total: "2111.00" },
    { id: "2", invdate: "2010-05-25", name: "test2", note: "note2", tax: "20.00", total: "320.00" },
    { id: "3", invdate: "2007-09-01", name: "test3", note: "note3", tax: "30.00", total: "430.00" },
    { id: "4", invdate: "2007-10-04", name: "test", note: "note", tax: "10.00", total: "210.00" },
    { id: "5", invdate: "2007-10-05", name: "test2", note: "note2", tax: "20.00", total: "320.00" },
    { id: "6", invdate: "2007-09-06", name: "test3", note: "note3", tax: "30.00", total: "430.00" },
    { id: "7", invdate: "2007-10-04", name: "test", note: "note", tax: "10.00", total: "210.00" },
    { id: "8", invdate: "2007-10-03", name: "test2", note: "note2", amount: "300.00", tax: "21.00", total: "320.00" },
    { id: "9", invdate: "2007-09-01", name: "test3", note: "note3", amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", total: "430.00" },
    { id: "11", invdate: "2007-10-01", name: "test", note: "note", amount: "200.00", tax: "10.00", total: "210.00" },
    { id: "12", invdate: "2007-10-02", name: "test2", note: "note2", amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", total: "320.00" },
    { id: "13", invdate: "2007-09-01", name: "test3", note: "note3", amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", total: "430.00" },
    { id: "14", invdate: "2007-10-04", name: "test", note: "note", amount: "200.00", tax: "10.00", total: "210.00" },
    { id: "15", invdate: "2007-10-05", name: "test2", note: "note2", amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", total: "320.00" },
    { id: "16", invdate: "2007-09-06", name: "test3", note: "note3", amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", total: "430.00" },
    { id: "17", invdate: "2007-10-04", name: "test", note: "note", amount: "200.00", tax: "10.00", total: "210.00" },
    { id: "18", invdate: "2007-10-03", name: "test2", note: "note2", amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", total: "320.00" },
    { id: "19", invdate: "2007-09-01", name: "test3", note: "note3", amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", total: "430.00" },
    { id: "21", invdate: "2007-10-01", name: "test", note: "note", amount: "200.00", tax: "10.00", total: "210.00" },
    { id: "22", invdate: "2007-10-02", name: "test2", note: "note2", amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", total: "320.00" },
    { id: "23", invdate: "2007-09-01", name: "test3", note: "note3", amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", total: "430.00" },
    { id: "24", invdate: "2007-10-04", name: "test", note: "note", amount: "200.00", tax: "10.00", total: "210.00" },
    { id: "25", invdate: "2007-10-05", name: "test2", note: "note2", amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", total: "320.00" },
    { id: "26", invdate: "2007-09-06", name: "test3", note: "note3", amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", total: "430.00" },
    { id: "27", invdate: "2007-10-04", name: "test", note: "note", amount: "200.00", tax: "10.00", total: "210.00" },
    { id: "28", invdate: "2007-10-03", name: "test2", note: "note2", amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", total: "320.00" },
    { id: "29", invdate: "2007-09-01", name: "test3", note: "note3", amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", total: "430.00" }
];
           jQuery("#list47").jqGrid({
               data: mydata,
               datatype: "local",
               height: 150,
               rowNum: 10,
               rowList: [10, 20, 30],
               colNames: ['Inv No', 'Date', 'Client', 'Amount', 'Tax', 'Total', 'Notes'],
               colModel: [
    { name: 'id', index: 'id', width: 60, sorttype: "int" },
    { name: 'invdate', index: 'invdate', width: 90, sorttype: "date", formatter: "date" },
    { name: 'name', index: 'name', width: 100 },
    { name: 'amount', index: 'amount', width: 80, align: "right", sorttype: "float", formatter: "number" },
    { name: 'tax', index: 'tax', width: 80, align: "right", sorttype: "float" },
    { name: 'total', index: 'total', width: 80, align: "right", sorttype: "float" },
    { name: 'note', index: 'note', width: 150, sortable: false }
],
               pager: "#plist47",
               viewrecords: true,
               caption: "Manipulating Array Data"
           });

       </script>    

</head>

<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

   <table id="list47"></table>
<div id="plist47"></div>


    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put all of the jqGrid code inside of the [ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) event, so that it is called after the page's DOM has been loaded:

```
jQuery(document).ready( function(){
  var mydata = [

  ...

      caption: "Manipulating Array Data"
  });
```

});

Comment: Exactly, Justin! I want also add that neha pathare should include jquery-ui-1.8.1.custom.min.js script better after jquery.js